# How to upload a big excel with merged cells to springboot api and save only a selected data from it to database

Tags: java, excel, postgresql, spring-boot, apache-poi

I have got an excel which I need to upload to an API using java, spring boot. The excel has many merged cells in it. It is a huge file of more than 2 MB. While uploading, I need to save some (not all, but selected field values) to PostgreSQL DB. Using apache poi and a small simple excel with no merged cells, I can upload the entire content to a table. But what I need is to save only few values from a huge excel with merged cells to DB while it gets uploaded to the api server. How to do that?

Comment: Please go through the [Help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). Especially read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Problems with your current question are: 1. You say, you can solve what you need using "a small simple excel with no merged cells". But you do not tell us where exactly you are stuck when using "a huge excel with merged cells". (Btw.: 2 MB is not that huge.) 2. You say, you need "not all, but selected field values". But you do not tell us what "selected field values" means. Do you mean only the cells which were selected before last saving?